# Gparted and installed don't see partitions after boot-repair

Tags: boot, partitioning, gparted, boot-repair, fdisk

I'm trying to fix my friend's computer after it got borked by a power surge. It can boot fine from USB, but if you boot the disk, it makes it to grub and then fails no matter which you select. He had it set up dual-booting Ubuntu and Windows. I tried running boot repair from the boot-repair live cd, and it gave me this paste - http://paste.ubuntu.com/8476018/ - but it failed to fix anything. Based on that I think the problem is in the Windows partition on sda2, which is designated as the boot partition.

I then decided I wanted to just try reinstalling Ubuntu on its partition, but neither the Ubuntu installer from the live disk nor Gparted can see any of the partitions, but rather see everything as unallocated, which I take to mean that the partition table is corrupted. The output of `fdisk -lu` is

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x6a4993a7

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048      411647      204800    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2   *      411648   309175128   154381740+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       309176320   525414399   108119040   83  Linux
/dev/sda4       525414456   625153409    49869477    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       525416448   533389295     3986424   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       594198528   624920575    15361024    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

I've found lots of similar things on other forums and questions, but I'm out of my depth telling what the actual problem is and don't want to make it worse by flailing blindly. My goals are to reinstall Ubuntu over the existing Ubuntu partition, and to get the data off the Windows partition. Much thanks for any pointers!

Comment: If there is an exclamation mark beside the disk entry in GParted, double-click on it to see if there is a clue to the problem in the information dialog.  Alternatively, you can run "sudo parted /dev/sda unit s print" and add the output to this problem report.